# Roblox PathFindingService Error how to fix?

Tags: algorithm, syntax-error, roblox

So  I got this error I'm trying to test a NPC to go to a waypoint. But then I get a error!

https://i.stack.imgur.com/16DuR.png

Is there a fix to IT?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/16DuR.png

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, Heyo, could you update your question with your code sample? Posting images of codes isn't helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is completely broken, please read the documentation and write your code based on it: https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/articles/Pathfinding

Comment: Their code looks like it's based off the code samples in this article.

Comment: Except he defined the waypoints in a wrong way, didn't put the command to jump, and didn't use a function system, instead of a while loop, and for that, you need to create lots of functions and redesign the whole code.

Comment: The for loop shown in the article is to create parts so you can see the waypoints, not to make the NPC walk. The whole walk system is made with functions that are connected when the NPC finishes walking to the waypoint.